# Image not loading on Squarespace page

Tags: image, squarespace

I made a simple change on my Squarespace site today, and for some reason my images on one specific page are not loading anymore.  I've tried different browsers, and clearing my cache, but the image won't load and nothing has changed.  Any idea what I can do to get to the bottom of this?

If you follow [this link](http://manousheh.com/menu) you will see what I'm talking about, and image will load for less than a second and then disappear.  If you don't see it, try refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are applying some custom CSS to the page in question, likely via [per-page code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection#toc-per-page-code-injection). The following code is appearing on that page:

```
<style>
.sublogo {
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:35px;
}  

.thumb-image.loaded {
   display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

It is the second rule, `.thumb-image.loaded {...}` that is causing the image to disappear once it is fully loaded.

Removing that rule should solve the issue. Of course, you'd need to consider why the rule was added in the first place and what other issue it was put there to solve.

Comment: you got it!  Thanks!